# Swift - switch between Core ML Model

Tags: swift, swiftui, coreml, coremltools

I'm trying to compare predictions from different `MLModels` in `SwiftUI`. To do that I have to switch between them, but can't because every `ML` variable has its own class, so I get the error:

> Cannot assign value of type 'ModelOne' to type 'ModelTwo'

Here's an example code:

```
import Foundation
import CoreML
import SwiftUI

let modelone = { //declaration model 1
do {
    let config = MLModelConfiguration()
    return try ModelOne(configuration: config)
} catch {
    /*...*/
}
}()

let modeltwo = { //declaration model 2
do {
    let config = MLModelConfiguration()
    return try ModelTwo(configuration: config)
} catch {
    /*...*/
}
}()

var imageused : UIImage! //image to classify
var modelstring = ""     //string of model user chosen
var modelchosen = modelone

Button(action: { //button user decide to use model two
   modelstring = "Model Two"

}) {/*...*/}

/*...*/
func classifyphoto() {

    guard let image = imageused as UIImage?,
          let imagebuffer = image.convertToBuffer() else {
        return
        
    }
    if  modelstring == "Model Two" { //if the user chosen model two, use ModelTwo
        modelchosen = modeltwo // Error: Cannot assign value of type 'ModelOne' to type 'ModelTwo'
    } else {
        modelchosen = modelone}
    
    let output = try? modelchosen.prediction(image: imagebuffer) //prediction with model chosen
 
    if let output = output {
        let results = output.classLabelProbs.sorted { $0.1 > $1.1 }
        _ = results.map { /*...*/
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: What is the return type of the two models? Are they the same?

Comment: I need to see your class declarations for ModelOne and ModelTwo.

Comment: For each MLModel adopted there's a type, that's why I have the error "Cannot assign value of type 'ModelOne' to type 'ModelTwo'". For example for "modelone" `let output: ModelOneOutput` and for "modeltwo" `let output: ModelTwoOutput`... @LouisLac

Comment: @JeshuaLacock Hi, the declaration of the models are reported above, in the code I attached..., the definitions are these: 
`class ModelOne {
    let model: MLModel
 class var urlOfModelInThisBundle : URL {
        let bundle = Bundle(for: self)
        return bundle.url(forResource: "ModelOne", withExtension:"mlmodelc")!
    }

     init(model: MLModel) {
        self.model = model
    } /*....*/,` I don't know if you were looking for these, I don't have any other declarations

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Swift is a statically typed language which means that in the general case you cannot assign a variable of one type to a variable of another type:

```swift
var int: Int = 42
int = "Hello, world!"  // Not allowed: cannot assign String to Int
```

The problem is that `modelchosen` is of type `ModelOne` since it is initialized with `modelone`, thus, you cannot later assign `modeltwo` to it as you are trying to do.

To make that working, you have first to identify the common capabilities of `ModelOne` and `ModelTwo`. Take a look at their definition. For instance, do their `.predict(image:)` method return the same type? It looks like you are trying to do image classification, so a common capability could be the capability to return a `String` describing the image (or a list of potential objects, etc.).

When you'll have identified the common capability, you'll be able to define the common interface of your different types. This common interface can be expressed in many ways:

- Using a base class
- Using a protocol
- Using an enum with payloads (union)

The following examples suppose that the common capabilities are:

- The two networks can both be initialized with a `MLModelConfiuration`
- They are used for image classification, i.e. they predict label (a `String`) describing a given image

#### Using a base class

The base class definition expresses those requirements like this:

```swift
class MLClassifier {
  init(from config: MLModelConfig) { 
    fatalError("not implemented")
  }

  func classify(image: ImageBuffer) -> String {
    fatalError("not implemented")
  }
}
```

You then derive this base class for the two models (example with the first one:

```swift
final class ModelOne: MLClassifier {
  init(from config: MLModelConfig) {
    // the specific implementation for `ModelOne`...
  }

  func classify(image: ImageBuffer) -> String {
    // the specific implementation for `ModelOne`..
  }
}
```

Finally, you can make the variable `modelchosen` to be of type `MLClassifier` to erase the underlying concrete type of the model:

```swift
var modelchosen: MLClassifier = ModelOne(from: config1)
```

As `MLClassifier` is a common base class for both `ModelOne` and `ModelTwo` you can dynamically change the type of `modelchosen` whenever you need:

```swift
// Later...
modelchosen = ModelTwo(from: config2)
```

The variable `modelchosen` being of type `MLClassifier` ensures that you can call the `.classify(image:)` method whatever the concrete model type is:

```swift
func classifyphoto() {
    guard let image = imageused as UIImage?,
          let imagebuffer = image.convertToBuffer() else {
        return
        
    }
    
    let output = modelchosen.classify(image: imageBuffer)
    // Update the UI...
}
```

#### Using protocols

Protocols are the modern and preferred way of expressing common interfaces in Swift, they should be used over classes when possible:

```swift
protocol MLClassifier {
  init(from config: MLModelConfig)
  func classify(image: ImageBuffer) -> String
}

// Implement the protocol for your models
struct ModelOne: MLClassifier {
  init(from config: MLModelConfig) { ... }
  func classify(image: ImageBuffer) -> String { ... }
}

// Store an instance of any `MLClassfier` using an existential
var classifier: any MLClassifier = ModelOne(from: config1)

// Later...
classifier = ModelTwo(from: config2)
```

---

To sum up, the key is to identify the common capabilities of the different types you are trying to unify. For instance, if the two models output at some point a `classLabelProbs` of the *same* type, then you could use this as the common abstraction.

---

As a last resort, you could wrap everything in a big `if-else` statement, event though it is not recommended since it is not very readable, is not a good way to encapsulate common behavior and leads to a lot of code repetition:

```swift
func classifyphoto() {
    guard let image = imageused as UIImage?,
          let imagebuffer = image.convertToBuffer() else {
        return
        
    }

    if modelstring == "Model Two" {
        // Use modeltwo
        let output = try? modeltwo.prediction(image: imagebuffer)
 
        if let output = output {
        let results = output.classLabelProbs.sorted { $0.1 > $1.1 }
        _ = results.map { /*...*/ }
    } else {
        // Use modelone
        let output = try? modelone.prediction(image: imagebuffer)
 
        if let output = output {
        let results = output.classLabelProbs.sorted { $0.1 > $1.1 }
        _ = results.map { /*...*/ }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, you wrote a full documentation here. I still have to try using protocol, but I've tried with if-else and it worked! Well, it's not elegant but a build succedeed is always  a build succedeed 

Comment: @LucasSWift Fair enough! Protocols help define a common interface to several types and are greatly useful in situations like yours, you should definitely learn how to use them!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the two model classes do not have a common class or common inherited class. There are several ways to implement what you want. I think this is the best way based on your example.

```
class MyModel {

    var model: MLModel? = nil

    init(modelName: String) {
    
        let bundle = Bundle.main
    
        if let modelURL = bundle.url(forResource: modelName, withExtension:"mlmodelc") {
    
            do {
                self.model = try MLModel(contentsOf: modelURL)
            }
            catch  {
                print("Unable to open MLModel: \(error)")
            }
        }
    }
}

class TestModel {

    class func testModels() {
        let modelOne = MyModel(modelName: "ModelOne")
        let modelTwo = MyModel(modelName: "ModelTwo")
    
        var selectedModel = modelOne
        selectedModel = modelTwo
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks this solved the issue with the classes! unfortunately cannot use `let output = try? selectedModel.prediction(image: imagebuffer)` because `Value of type "MyMode" ha no member "prediction"`

Comment: You have to use the model property. Like: let output = try? selectedModel.model.prediction(image: imagebuffer)

Comment: with let output = `try? selectedModel.model.prediction(image: imagebuffer) ` I'm still having issues: `Argument type 'CVPixelBuffer' (aka 'CVBuffer') does not conform to expected type 'MLFeatureProvider'` and `Value of optional type 'MLModel?' must be unwrapped to refer to member 'prediction' of wrapped base type 'MLModel'`

Comment: I suggest you learn how to use optionals or ask an alternate question, and you must not be passing an MLFeatureProvider. These are additional questions, I believe I've answered your original question.

Comment: I would just answer your additional questions here, but it is too difficult to write code in the comments.